# Does anyone know how to resolve this reflection issue?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, shaders

I want these two truss to work as one in term of reflection but don't know how to make them one. I have tried joining them by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> but not working.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello, in what way do they not work as one object? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Look at the two stacked trusses, In real world in terms of reflection they would act as one and Reflection would be smooth but not repeatedly on both truss.